# How to customize posts in WordPress by using HTML and CSS?

Tags: php, posts, css, html

I've tried to find the information on the Internet and stackoverflow, but there is nothing about it.

So I've migrated my website(html,css,js) to WordPress(index.php,header.php,footer.php etc) and I can't figure out how to change a view of posts before adding them to my site.

I can see 4 ways of doing that:

1)Download WP plugin to add and customize posts. But I'll only be able to customize it by using the admin area, I can't do it with HTML and CSS, very few options(color,picture etc)

2)Create a separate file(sidebar.php) and add to it my posts. But if my client wants to add posts himself, he won't be able to do that, and again very few options. [example](https://prnt.sc/lhmhoy)

3)Use the standard "Posts-Add New" in the admin area. But in that case, I can't figure out how to cusomize it, what shall I do?Go into the "wp-admin" folder which is in the WordPress file and find HTML,CSS which are responsible for changing posts view and change them? Because if I don't change them, this happens [example](https://prnt.sc/lhmk36)

4) Migrate my website to WordPress by using a blank theme [example](https://underscores.me/). There is a posts page(posts.php,I don't remeber how it's called exactly) and try to find a code snippet which is responsible for a posts view

My question is how to change a view of posts in WordPress? And this is what I want to make [example](https://prnt.sc/lhmm7d) [link to the website](http://www.themechampion.com/demo/industriallive/)

Comment: You're essentially just asking "How do I build a WordPress theme". It's *far* too broad a topic for a single question. Please start with the [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) and go from there. If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask those, but please search to see if it's already been answered before you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing you need to do is implementing the html template you desire to something that called [wordpress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

is good to start with blank wordpress theme like underscores.me, so you can freely custom your own template

so, after your files is ready, you can learn about [wordpress theme customizer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

im giving you best tutorial and practice here [taniarascia.com](https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/).
hope it'll helps

*wordpress development is hard at the beginning.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I've found one video which is probably related to the topic, please check it out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHyLKISuLjQ, is it exactly what I'm looking for?

Comment: good tutorial video, slightly match with your actually need is, but if you want something like your example link you posted above, i suggest you learn wordpress theme customizer first

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing CSS classes and HTML of the posts themselves, do not forget that you can do this at the database level via search and replace. 
Additionally, check out wp-cli, which may be even easier, as it handles serialization issues as well.
This is how I do most site conversions, when I bring in posts from a legacy system.